# Java.security - how to store KeyPair keys in a String. I get Invalid DER encoding exceptions

Tags: java, security, rsa

Generating a Keypair, encoding and decoding with byte array works fine.

I would like to store both the private and public keys as Strings. This is for experimenting purposes. I would like to investigate how I can store a password that has to be decoded before used.

I used string.getBytes() and new String( bytes) to convert the byte array to a String and vv.

When I try to store & retrieve these byte arrays with Strings, use them encoding a secret text, then I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() --
>   **Invalid DER encoding, not ended**

**The solution**, thanks to James K Polk, is in the answer.

Comment: You don't. You store them in byte arrays. `String` is not a container for binary data.

Comment: no, no, no, no! If you must store arbitrary byte sequences as character data then you need to use an appropriate encoding. The most common and widely supported such encoding is base64, so use that.

Comment: @James K Polk, Thank you very much, this really helps. Please add as an answer and I will v and +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @James K Polk!! This really helped me in finishing my experiments! When you post an answer I will "V" and "+1" that answer!

Using the answer of James K Polk, I rewrote the experimental example:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class KeyPairToString {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] publicKey, byte[] inputData) throws Exception {
        PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)    /* ExceptionL Invalid DER encoding */
                .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inputData);
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] privateKey, byte[] inputData) throws Exception {
        PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)
                .generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inputData);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateKeyPair()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        keyGen.initialize(512, random);
        return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    private static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static byte[] stringToBytes(String astring) {
        return astring.getBytes();
    }

    private static String bytesToEncodedString(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }

    private static byte[] encodedStringToBytes(String encodedString) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPair generateKeyPair = generateKeyPair();

        byte[] publicKey = generateKeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKey = generateKeyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

        // Byte array
        String secretText = "hi this is secret johan here";
        byte[] encryptedData = encrypt(publicKey, secretText.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(privateKey, encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData));

        // Now with Strings
        String encodedPublicKeyString = bytesToEncodedString(publicKey);
        String encodedPrivateKeyString = bytesToEncodedString(privateKey);
        String encryptedDataString = bytesToEncodedString(
                encrypt(encodedStringToBytes(encodedPublicKeyString), stringToBytes(secretText)));
        String decryptedDataString = bytesToString(
                decrypt(
                        encodedStringToBytes(encodedPrivateKeyString),
                        encodedStringToBytes(encryptedDataString)));
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedDataString));
    }
}
```